# NULL rows and IS NULL

Tags: postgresql, null, composite-types

I've been writing some queries that look like this:

```sql
SELECT
  ...
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN table_c c
  ON c.id = a.id
```

In these queries only one of the joins can be successful. In other words, a row from `table_a` is matched by either a row from `table_b` or a row from `table_c`.

In the select list, there is some logic based on which join succeeds. I can test this by doing the following:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN b IS NULL THEN
      -- do something
    ELSE NULL
  END
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN table_c c
  ON c.id = a.id
```

When testing if a row is `NULL` you can use the table alias in an `IS NULL` expression, but it does not work as expected in an `IS NOT NULL` expression. If there are columns in `table_b` that are not `NULL`, the expression `table_b IS NOT NULL` will return `FALSE`.

However, the expression `NOT (table_b IS NULL)` will return `TRUE` as expected.

Why this is the case?

Comment: See [(x IS NOT NULL) vs (NOT x IS NULL) in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/157691/7119).

Comment: Composite types and `NULL` checking is fraught with danger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sad story.

When the SQL standard committee defined the `NULL`-ness of composite values, they must have taken the wrong drugs.

Anyway, they ruled that a composite `IS NULL` if all elements are `NULL`, and *that a composite `IS NOT NULL` if **all elements are `NOT NULL`***.

In other words, there are composites that are neither `NULL` nor `NOT NULL`.

PostgreSQL implements that, but treats composites as `NOT NULL` in most other respects. There have been discussions about this, but in the face of the standard's definitions, nobody could come up with a consistent solution.

This is a mess, and you are well advised not to think too hard about this if you want to keep your peace of mind.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm already thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

[What Laurenz said.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/250493/3684)

Plus, `NOT (b IS NULL)` works as expected, as you found yourself. But it will be less confusing and a bit faster to test the column in the join expression instead:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN -- some expression
               --^-- the column used in the join
          ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   table_a a
LEFT   JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.id
LEFT   JOIN table_c c ON c.id = a.id;
```

That column is `NOT NULL` if (and only if) a matching row has been found.

Related:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026085/939860)
- [(x IS NOT NULL) vs (NOT x IS NULL) in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157691/x-is-not-null-vs-not-x-is-null-in-postgresql)