# PostgreSQL's record type returning null?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, null

I don't understand why this result is possible. Can someone explain why the first assert returns `true` and the second `false`? `generate_token()` is a function that generates a random `bytea` and inserts it into a certain table, then the inserted row is returned. The function itself is working fine. Running through a .pgsql script.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    test record;
BEGIN

select * into test from generate_token('test');

--returns true
assert test.token IS NOT NULL;
--returns false, which breaks.
assert test IS NOT NULL;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Disclosing the exact signature of the function `generate_token()` (including the return type) would be instrumental for the question. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... then the inserted row is returned.

It's safe to assume there are multiple fields in that returned row. If at least one additional field is `NULL`, then the row value is neither `NULL` nor `NOT NULL`. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html):

> If the ***`expression`*** is row-valued, then `IS NULL` is true when
> the row expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are
> null, while `IS NOT NULL` is true when the row expression itself is
> non-null and all the row's fields are non-null. Because of this
> behavior, `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` do not always return inverse
> results for row-valued expressions; in particular, **a row-valued
> expression that contains both null and non-null fields will return
> false for both tests**.

Bold emphasis mine.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=763018099f6217847408fc317ca8348d)*

Related:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026085/939860)
- [(x IS NOT NULL) vs (NOT x IS NULL) in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157691/x-is-not-null-vs-not-x-is-null-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thats a really weird interaction... In OO it is safe to assume that an object's field can be null while the object itself is not.. Living and learning... Thanks!

Comment: @rdnobrega Yes, the SQL standard committee must have smoked something weird when they decreed that.